# Loop through API response with pagination

Tags: php, api

I'm making an api call that return only 100 records:

```
$response = $api->order->{"events"}->get();
```

To get next 100 records I have to call api with last ID from response, for example:

```
$response = $api->order->{"events?from=LAST_ID"}->get();
```

So how to make iteration to get all records?

Comment: Please include a sample of the data that is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task in different projects, and I use a `while()` iteration. It might not be the cleanest solution, but it gets the job done.

```
$response = $api->order->{"events"}->get();  

while ( $response->count > 0 ) :

        // Do something with $response

        $response = $api->order->{"events?from=LAST_ID"}->get();

endwhile;
```